# Is there a vbo to get value from a collection based on value of other fields and save it as a data item?

Tags: blueprism

Relatively new to Blue Prism,

I have a collection that looks like this, with 100+ rows:

| Results | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| Timestamp | 8 Apr 2021 |
| Name | ABC |

I'd like to manipulate the data such that if Results = 'Name', Get the Answer (aka ABC) and put it into a data item.

Is there any way to do this?
I understand I could hardcode i.e. Get value based on Row Index and Column Index, but my data is complex and may not always have the same rox index.

Comment: The solution would be to loop all rows of the Collection and do the comparison yourself until `[Collection.Results] = "Name"`, then using a Calculation stage to store the value in a Data Item yourself. Does this meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the collection filter to get a collection output? The utility has an action to filter where you can input a collection and then use

```
[FieldName] Like "some value"
```

This would result in every complete row in the collection that matches the filter.